# Font Awesome not working in offline mode

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, offline

i am using **font-awesome** icons for publishing my HTML,CSS templates. They are working fine when i have the live link but when  i download the CSS file and include that in my pages icon disappears.

Live Path : `<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Local Path : `<link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">`

How can i use the font awesome in offline mode?

Comment: Just download that css, and include in header :)
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome-4.3.0.zip

and check path to css.. :)

Comment: open http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css and see how to connect the font. Where you is the font?

Comment: @Dmitriy thanx i have included the font folder and it is working fine know :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also need to download the fonts themselves as well...It is a font, like any other...So, go to fontawesome website, follow the instructions and download css + fonts :)

Answer (score 18):

Did you embed FontAwesome font into your project?
your structure must be like this:

```
[+]assets
    [+]css
        font-awesome.css
    [+]js
        demo-file.js
    [+]fonts
        fontawesome-webfont.eot
        fontawesome-webfont.svg
        fontawesome-webfont.ttf
        fontawesome-webfont.woff
        fontawesome-webfont.woff2
index.html
sample.html
whatever.html
```

after that, you can use FontAwesome locally.

Comment: Thanks! i have forgotten to define this!

Answer (score 3):

Could be a pathname problem Try:

```
<link href="./css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you didn't download fonts or you used the wrong path.
You can download the latest version font awesome at https://fontawesome.com/download.
And don't forget check your path!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case: If you have added something like this in your html (or any other font family with important using * selector), then this might be the cause your icons are not showing..

```
*{
   font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif !important;
 }
```